How to implement a custom cell renderer in a custom library data grid in Angular 16 and above?
angular17

I need to create a custom library for my angular project.
I need to implement a data grid like ag-grid without using any external packages/libraries like ag-grid.
I have created this data grid with pagination, sorting, searching, column filtering.
I would like to create a dynamic component or something like that which will accept any cell renderer component and bind it in the data grid table.
The cell renderer can be any it will be passed along with the column defs.
It should then render it's template content in the cell of a table.
Below is what I have tried so far.

Grid view component is part of the library and a standalone component:
<table [class]="tableStyle">
    <thead class="header-row">
      <tr [class]="headerStyle">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let header of gridData.colDefs; let i = index">
          <th [class.frozen-column]="gridData.frozenColumn === header.field">
            <span [ngStyle]="{
                cursor: header.field !== 'Action' ? 'pointer' : 'default'
              }" (click)="header.field !== 'Action' && sortData(header.field)">
              {{ header.field }}
              <span style="float: right" *ngIf="sortColumn === header.field && header.field !== 'Action'">
                {{ sortDirection === "asc" ? "▲" : "▼" }}
              </span>
            </span>
          </th>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
      <tr *ngIf="gridData.searchableColumns">
        <ng-container *ngFor="let header of gridData.colDefs; let i = index">
          <td [class.frozen-column]="gridData.frozenColumn == header.field">
            <input id="{{ header }}" [class]="columnFilterCss" *ngIf="
                gridData.searchableColumns &&
                gridData.searchableColumns.includes(header.field) &&
                header.field !== 'Action'
              " type="text" [(ngModel)]="columnFilters[header.field]" (input)="applyColumnFilter(header.field)"
              placeholder="Search {{ header.field }}" />
          </td>
        </ng-container>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <ng-container *ngIf="totalItems > 0; else noRecordsFound">
        <tr [class]="rowStyle" *ngFor="let row of filteredData">
          <ng-container *ngFor="let header of gridData.colDefs">
            <td [class.frozen-column]="gridData.frozenColumn === header.field" *ngIf="header.field != 'Action'">
              <!-- <span *ngIf="header.cellRenderer">
                <easy-dynamic [component]="header.cellRenderer"></easy-dynamic>
              </span>
              <span [innerHTML]="
                  (header.field !== 'Action' ? row[header.field] : '')
                    | safeHtml
                "></span> -->

              <div *ngIf="header.cellRenderer">
                <!-- <app-image-cell-renderer [value]="row[header.field]"></app-image-cell-renderer> -->
              </div>
              <div *ngIf="header.field !== 'Action' && !header.cellRenderer">
                {{ row[header.field] }}
              </div>
            <td *ngIf="header.field === 'Action'" [class.frozen-column]>
              <button *ngFor="let data of gridData.action" (click)="data.callbackFunc(row)" [class]="data.css">
                <ng-container *ngIf="data.text; else iconOrImage">
                  {{ data.text }}
                </ng-container>
                <ng-template #iconOrImage>
                  <ng-container *ngIf="data.icon; else image">
                    <i [class]="data.icon"></i>
                  </ng-container>
                  <ng-template #image>
                    <img [src]="data.image" [class]="data.css" />
                  </ng-template>
                </ng-template>
              </button>
            </td>
          </ng-container>
        </tr>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-template #noRecordsFound>
        <tr>
          <td style="text-align: center; font-size: x-large" [attr.colspan]="gridData.colDefs.length">
            No records found
          </td>
        </tr>
      </ng-template>
    </tbody>
  </table>

cell renderer is part of the mail application
export class ImageCellRendererComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() value: any;
  displayValue: string = '';
  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.displayValue = this.value;
  }

  showDefault(event: any) {
    event.target.src = '/assets/images/default-image.jpg';
  }
}

//template
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-2">
    <div>
      <img [src]="displayValue" alt="" class="rounded-circle avatar-md" (error)="showDefault($event)" />
    </div>
  </div>
</div>


Column defs is passed from main application to the grid component in the library.
columnDefs: IColDefs[] = [
    { field: 'Id' },
    { field: 'Name', cellRenderer: ImageCellRendererComponent },
    { field: 'Designation' },
    { field: 'Department' },
  ];

